# Nim checks:off vs -d:release

Tags: performance, optimization, release, nim-lang

I'd like to know what's the difference between both options. At first i thought they would produce the same output, but i have profiled a code using first `{.checks:off.}` and later `-d:release` and the difference is notable (release being more faster).

The code in this case is a hot loop with some float operations, one if and array get/set.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what release does: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/devel/config/nim.cfg#L50-L66

```
@if release or quick:
  obj_checks:off
  field_checks:off
  range_checks:off
  bound_checks:off
  overflow_checks:off
  assertions:off
  stacktrace:off
  linetrace:off
  debugger:off
  line_dir:off
  dead_code_elim:on
@end

@if release:
  opt:speed
@end
```

`opt:speed` then tells your C compiler to optimize the output for speed, for example:

```
gcc.options.speed = "-O3 -fno-strict-aliasing"
```

Comment: Then, what does disabling checks do? i was under the impression that it would disable every *_checks option. In my case probably `checks:off` didn't disable bound checking

Answer (score 2):

`-d:release` also enables the optimiser (which does some extras such as removing `assert`s) which will be causing some speed increases on its behalf. The flags are descibed [here](https://nim-lang.org/docs/nimc.html#additional-compilation-switches).